# Django NoReverseMatch Error while navigating to Category Page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm getting `No reverse match` **error** for `sports_detail` when I click on category, what I'm doing is when I click on category all posts related mapped to that category will get render on `sport_category` page using `ListView`.
What I'm not getting is why I'm getting `No reverse match` **error** for `sports_details`.
Same thing I did for My `blogs` section and it's working fine, but not sure why it's not working for `Sports` section.
Any Help in what I'm doing wrong?
I tried removing **p** from `url` but it's still not working, modified `url` below:

```
path('sports/<str:name>', SportsCategory.as_view(), name="categories"),
```

Code: https://pastebin.com/TsN8UcKW

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your **html** you have a line:

```
{% if category.1 != 0 %}
```

can you explain better what it means?

Also I presume your error is in this line here:

```
<a href="{% url 'categories' category.0 %}" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
```

instead of writing `{% url 'categories' category.0 %}` write `{% url 'categories' category.pk %}`